# How to load a column with multiple values into separate lines into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ms-access

I have an Excel sheet that looks as given below:

```
+---------+----------------+
| ItemNum |  Substitutes   |
+---------+----------------+
| ABCD    | XXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ |
| PQRS    | AAAA/BBBB/CCCC |
+---------+----------------+
```

I need to load this into a table in MS Access or SQL Server in the following way:

```
+---------+------------+
| ItemNum | Substitute |
+---------+------------+
| ABCD    | XXXX       |
| ABCD    | YYYY       |
| ABCD    | ZZZZ       |
| PQRS    | AAAA       |
| PQRS    | BBBB       |
| PQRS    | CCCC       |
+---------+------------+
```

Kindly advise on a way to do this. I know there is a way to do this using Excel VBA. But I am looking for options that are macro - free wherein the file as is can be loaded into a staging table and then using SQL it can be obtained in the desired form.

Comment: `But I am looking for options that are macro - free` Why tag it with `Excel-VBA` then :) I have removed the Tag. If you are open to VBA then please re-add the tag and remove that line from your post

Comment: Are their always going to be 3 values in the `substitutes` column?

Comment: Also, are the values always 4 characters long or varying lengths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the data as is, then you can use this query to split them down:

```
SELECT T1.ItemNum, T2.mySplits as Substitute
FROM
 (
  SELECT *,
  CAST('<X>'+replace(T.Substitutes,'/','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
  FROM Table1 T
 ) T1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as mySplits
 FROM T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
 ) T2
```

Here's an Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/042da/2

Comment: I like this answer. It works even for weird data inputs like `AAAA1234/BBBBxx/CCCCd//SSSS`. It correctly put in the null value and didn't care about my lengths or numbers since it's a varchar.

Comment: Thank you John for the very robust solution. As clesiemo3 mentioned, it is very flexible to different inputs. I should have mentioned this in the question but though the names follow standards we have a few outliers in the data. This would handle them very well. I would like to understand this query indepth. Kindly let me know where I can read up on how this query works.

Comment: Hi Manus. I'd read up the BOL here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx. It's fairly in depth and explains everything clearly. Then have a look around various blogs. There's loads of examples of this online.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a staging table approach.  Because you have this tagged for both SQL Server and Access, here are two options.

If you *know* the codes are always the same length, then put the data in a staging table and extract with something like:

```
select ItemNum, substring(substitutes, 1, 4) as substitute
from staging
where substitutes is not null
union all
select ItemNum, substring(substitutes, 6, 4) as substitute
from staging
where substitutes like '%/%'
union all
select ItemNum, substring(substitutes, 10, 4) as substitute
from staging
where substitutes like '%/%/%'
```

and so on.  This is intentionally written in a way that can be easily modified to run in MS Access.

The second choice is similar, but does the pivoting in Excel.  Use *Data --> Text To Columns* to split the data into separate columns.  Then, load them into a table with columns like `substitute1`, and so on.   You then want a query like:

```
select ItemNum, substitute1 as substitute
from staging
where substitute1 is not null
union all
select ItemNum, substitute2 as substitute
from staging
where substitute2 is not null
union all
select ItemNum, substitute3 as substitute
from staging
where substitute3 is not null
```

Once again, this query is intentionally written compatible with SQL Server and MS Access.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Your answer was sufficient for most of the test cases. But there were a few outliers in the data which made me go with John Bell's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have an SQL query above to be used for the import and that should be the preferred method. If you want to attempt a formula based solution within the worksheet, try this formula pair.

[image: Split with formula]

The formulas for D2:E2 are,

```
=OFFSET($A$2, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3),0)
=MID(OFFSET($A$2, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3), 1), MOD((ROW(1:1)-1)*5+1,15), 4)
```

Fill down as necessary. This may be viable as a one-time solution.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped for your input. It works but I was more interested in an SQL solution to this problem.